# Drawing Polygon with Dlib Swift

Tags: swift, dlib

I am using https://github.com/zweigraf/face-landmarking-ios for dlib with swift. I can draw line, dot with dlib library. However, I couldn't find a way to fill after drawing line with dlib library.

I would like to change lip color. I try to use with CALayer but too slow and not real time like dlib. Is it possible way to fill color in dlib ?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. I am using SKScene with SpriteKit. Overlay on camera layer. Draw polygon in SKScene.

Comment: can you share it demo.